# Exporting back to ArcScene

Tags: export, import

I am trying to create surfaces in Blender using data from ArcScene. Using BlenderGIS I have imported my shapefile, exploded the polygons and lofted the ones I want together and smoothed them. I have tried exporting this as a collada file back into ArcScene but the result is just a mash of polygons that the software cannot interpret even though it thinks it can.

I guess the question here is how do I export a model from Blender back into ArcScene, preferably rectified if possible. I have attached an example of the file I am trying to put into ArcScene [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-IqfQ7bgpIwQl2xFYj9XSapHG433L1mX/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for any help,

Josh

Comment: Have you tried a different file format, what other files can ArcScene read?  If it displays well in Blender, it sounds like an issue with ArcScene or its importer. Does it happen with all other meshes you try to import or only this one? If so you might have a faulty mesh.

Comment: I tried a simpler mesh but that didn't work either. I think it may be the way that ArcScene is reading the file. I will try walk it through Sketchup when can get to a copy of it, maybe that will work. If anyone has any other ideas about how to bring 3D models from blender into ArcScene I would welcome them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question basically comes down to processing power and patience. The error I state above was solved by closing the program and trying again. The other issues come down to making sure that the normals are correct in Blender which was addressed by [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106958/wrl-not-scaling-correctly-on-import).

Making sure the computer has enough memory to cache all the data require is a must, I found that computers with more RAM and processing power could handle transforming shapes with higher face counts into multipatches. Having said that I suspect there may be a limit of about 50,000, but have yet to confirm this.